# Only have unique values (no duplicates) in a golang channel

Tags: go, channel

On IoT devices go applications are running that can receive commands from the cloud. The commands are pushed on a queue

```golang
var queue chan time.Time
```

and workers on the IoT device process the queue.

The job of the worker is to send back data covering a period of time to the cloud, the time on the channel is the start time of such a period. The IoT devices are on mobile network connection so sometimes data gets lost and never arrives at the cloud. The cloud also is not sure if the command it sent arrived on the IoT device and could get impatient and resend the command.

I want to make sure that if the original command is still in the queue the same command can not be pushed on the queue. Is there a way to do that?

```golang
func addToQueue(periodStart time.Time) error {
    if alreadyOnQueue(queue, periodStart) {
        return errors.New("periodStart was already on the queue, not adding it again")
    }
    queue <- periodStart
    return nil
}

func alreadyOnQueue(queue chan time.Time, t time.Time) bool {
    return false // todo
}
```

Comment: No, there is no functionality built into channels to do that. You'd have to de-duplicate the values yourself either at the sender or the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a solution that is available on https://github.com/munnik/uniqueue/

```golang
package uniqueue

import (
    "errors"
    "sync"
)

// UQ is a uniqueue queue. It guarantees that a value is only once in the queue. The queue is thread safe.
// The unique constraint can be temporarily disabled to add multiple instances of the same value to the queue.
type UQ[T comparable] struct {
    back                 chan T
    queue                chan T
    front                chan T
    constraints          map[T]*constraint
    mu                   sync.Mutex
    AutoRemoveConstraint bool // if true, the constraint will be removed when the value is popped from the queue.
}

type constraint struct {
    count    uint // number of elements in the queue
    disabled bool
}

func NewUQ[T comparable](size uint) *UQ[T] {
    u := &UQ[T]{
        back:        make(chan T),
        queue:       make(chan T, size),
        front:       make(chan T),
        constraints: map[T]*constraint{},
    }

    go u.linkChannels()

    return u
}

// Get the back of the queue, this channel can be used to write values to.
func (u *UQ[T]) Back() chan<- T {
    return u.back
}

// Get the front of the queue, this channel can be used to read values from.
func (u *UQ[T]) Front() <-chan T {
    return u.front
}

// Ignores the constraint for a value v once, when the value is added to the queue again, the constraint is enabled again.
func (u *UQ[T]) IgnoreConstraintFor(v T) {
    u.mu.Lock()
    defer u.mu.Unlock()

    if _, ok := u.constraints[v]; !ok {
        u.constraints[v] = &constraint{}
    }

    u.constraints[v].disabled = true
}

// Manually add a constraint to the queue, only use in special cases when you want to prevent certain values to enter the queue.
func (u *UQ[T]) AddConstraint(v T) error {
    u.mu.Lock()
    defer u.mu.Unlock()

    if _, ok := u.constraints[v]; !ok {
        u.constraints[v] = &constraint{
            count:    1,
            disabled: false,
        }
        return nil
    } else {
        if u.constraints[v].disabled {
            u.constraints[v].count += 1
            u.constraints[v].disabled = false
            return nil
        }
    }
    return errors.New("Already existing constraint prevents adding new constraint")
}

// Manually remove a constraint from the queue, this needs to be called when AutoRemoveConstraint is set to false. Useful when you want to remove the constraint only when a worker using the queue is finished processing the value.
func (u *UQ[T]) RemoveConstraint(v T) {
    u.mu.Lock()
    defer u.mu.Unlock()

    if _, ok := u.constraints[v]; ok {
        u.constraints[v].count -= 1
        if u.constraints[v].count == 0 {
            delete(u.constraints, v)
        }
    }
}

func (u *UQ[T]) linkChannels() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(2)

    go u.shiftToFront(wg)
    go u.readFromBack(wg)

    wg.Wait()
}

func (u *UQ[T]) shiftToFront(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for v := range u.queue {
        u.front <- v
        if u.AutoRemoveConstraint {
            u.RemoveConstraint(v)
        }
    }

    close(u.front)

    wg.Done()
}

func (u *UQ[T]) readFromBack(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for v := range u.back {
        if err := u.AddConstraint(v); err == nil {
            u.queue <- v
        }
    }

    close(u.queue)

    wg.Done()
}
```